# Default Struct Initialization in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, default

Say I have a struct that looks like this (a POD):

```
struct Foo
{
  int i;
  double d;
};
```

What are the differences between the following two lines:

```
Foo* f1 = new Foo;
Foo* f2 = new Foo();
```

Comment: Note the related question [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first one leaves the values uninitialised; the second initialises them to zero. This is only the case for POD types, which have no constructors.

Comment: Thank you! Is that the only difference?

Comment: Yes, that's the only difference.

Comment: And if I am not mistaken, this was only added in some newer revisions of the standard (2003?)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose nothing at all. `Foo()` is allowed, even if it makes no sense... I've tried to change `struct` into `class` and tried a diff on the generated exe, and they resulted to be the same, meaning that a class without method is like a struct from a practical and "effective" point of view.

**But**: if you use only **one** of the alternative, keeping `struct` or `class` no matter, it happens that `new Foo` and `new Foo()` gives executables which differ! (At least using g++) I.e.

```
struct Foo { int i; double d; }
int main() { Foo *f1 = new Foo; delete f1; }
```

is compiled into somehing different from

```
struct Foo { int i; double d; }
int main() { Foo *f1 = new Foo(); delete f1; }
```

and the same happens with `class` instead of `struct`. To know where the difference is we should look at the generated code... and to know if it is a g++ idiosincracy or not, I should try another compiler but I have only gcc and no time now to analyse the asm output of g++...

Anyway from a "functional" (practical) point of view, it is the same thing.

**Add**

At the end it is always better to know or do deeper investigation for some common human problems on Q/A sites... the only difference in the code generated by g++ in () and no () cases,

```
    movl    $0, (%eax)
    fldz
    fstpl   4(%eax)
```

which is a fragment that initializes to 0/0.0 the int and the double of the struct... so Seymour knows it better (but I could have discovered it without knowing if I had taken a look at the asm first!)

Comment: Why does using brackets make no sense, it is invoking the default constructor. If anything, a lack of parens makes no sense.

Comment: what are you saying? it's a test, plausible for the question and the fact that foo() normally means a call to a function/method; a not so useful test, rather than a reading of specs, this would have been a possible critic.Your comment means nothing to me.

Answer (score -2):

Per the link I posted.

> In C++ the only difference between a class and a struct is that class-members are private by default, while struct-members default to public. So structures can have constructors, and the syntax is the same as for classes.

[Struct Constructor Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127396/structure-constructor-in-c)

Comment: The point is the use or omission of the curved brackets when constructing new objects. The question applies to classes as well as structs.