# Regarding struct initialization in c++

Tags: c++, struct

I have Struct like these

```
 typedef struct sample
 {
       double x,
       double y,
       double z
 }s1;
 s1 s;
```

will the content in s variable initialized or not?

What will be the values of x,y,z?

thanks

Comment: Note that, in C++, you don't often see `typedef struct foo { ...`. This is because in C++, unlike C, all structs names are also type names. In C++ you can write: `struct sample {}; sample s;`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x`, `y` and `z` won't be initialized if `s` is defined in a function scope. They would be containing some unspecified values. At file scope the data members would be initialized to their default values.

In C++ however you can have a constructor initializer list to initialize the data members

For example

```
struct ABC
{
   int x;
   int y;

   ABC(): x(1),y(2){}
};

ABC s; // x and y initialized to 1 and 2 respectively
```

In C++ you also have [default initialization and value initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializati) to initialize data members.

Comment: @Jan : Yes it depends whether the object is defined at function scope or at file scope

Comment: But would't x and y be initialized with zeros if `s` declared in global scope?

Comment: @Prasoon: not much point agreeing with Jan down here... how about fixing your answer?

Comment: @Nightcracker: Never - I'm Australian - as Kim of (Kath and ~ fame) likes to say "NOW!".

Answer (score 4):

In the code you presented, the fields will be uninitialized. You can add a constructor (if you need/can), or in case you need the POD-ness (some part of your code depends on some of those properties) and you cannot add a constructor, you can still *value-initialize* the struct (i.e. set each member to 0) at the place of use:

```
struct sample        // typedef not required
{
   double x,
   double y,
   double z
};
sample s = sample(); // will set all members to 0.0
```

Now, if you want to initialize different members with some particular values, because it is an aggregate you can use aggregate initialization:

```
sample s = { 1.0, 3.0 };
```

That will set `x` to `1.0`, `y` to `3.0`. Since there is no value for `z`, the compiler will set it to `0.0`. Note that this means that `sample s = {};` is equivalent to `sample s = sample();`

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932781/why-is-a-pod-in-a-struct-zero-initialized-by-an-implicit-constructor-when-creatin) for more detailed description of default vs. value initalization.

Answer (score 2):

If it is C++, you could make constructor.

```
struct s1
{
  s1( const double x = 0.0, const double y = 0.0, const double z = 0.0 )
  : x(x), y(y), z(z)
  {
  };
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

s1 s;
```

Comment: But you don't have to make a constructor and still can zero-initialize them.

Comment: You should make that constructor `explicit`, any constructor that can be called with a single argument is prone to open up the system for unwanted conversions: `void foo( s1 const & ); foo( x );` If `x` is of arithmetic type, that code is probably an error, but will actually work by converting `x` to `s1` as `s1( x )` and then calling `foo`. It is usually safer to make the constructor explicit, and if the code above was intentional the user would have to explicitly request the conversion: `foo( s1(x) );` which is not too much of a burden.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in types like `double` and `int` are initialised if the variable is `static` or at `namespace`/file scope, otherwise - for efficiency reasons - they're not initialised unless a constructor indicates that's useful.

Note: this answer addresses the "s1 s;" situation you describe.  It is possible to provide an explicit initialisation when defining the variable, but that's another case.

To add a constructor so:

```
struct X
{
    X() : x_(0), y_(0), z_(0) { }
    double x, y, z;
};
```

Comment: Just as lacking as the other 2 answers that were already there.