# Initialize POD struct

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct POD
{
    int i;
    char c;
    bool b;
    double d;
};

void Func(POD *p) { ... // change the field of POD }    

void ModifyPOD(POD &pod)
{
    POD tmpPOD = {};
    pod = tmpPOD; // first initialize the pod
    Func(&pod);   // then call an API function that will modify the result of pod
                  // the document of the API says that the pass-in POD must be initialized first.
}

int main()
{
    POD pod;
    ModifyPOD(pod);    

    std::cout << "pod.i: " << pod.i;
    std::cout << ", pod.c: " << pod.c;
    std::cout << " , pod.b:" << pod.b;
    std::cout << " , pod.d:" << pod.d << std::endl;
}
```

Question> I need to design a function that modify the pass-in variable `pod`. Is the above function named as ModifyPOD correct? First, I initialize the struct by assigning it(i.e. pod) with the value from a local struct(i.e. tmpPOD). Then, the variable is passed to Func.
I use the local variable to initialize the pod so that I can avoid to do the following instead:

```
pod.i = 0;
pod.c = ' ';
pod.b = false;
pod.d = 0.0;
```

However, I am not sure whether this practice is legitimate or not.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932781/why-is-a-pod-in-a-struct-zero-initialized-by-an-implicit-constructor-when-creati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is legitimate. I''ll just add that you can do

```
pod = POD();
Func(&pod);
```

in the `ModifyPod()` function which is equivalent and simpler.

Comment: You can also do something along the lines of `POD pod = {1, 'A', true, 3.14};`