# Why do instance variables of run-time stack objects differ from heap objects?

Tags: c++, object, runtime, heap-memory, instance-variables

There may be other examples, but this is the one I just came across.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
  public:
    int x; 
};

int main()
{
  Student rts;
  Student* heap = new Student;

  cout << rts.x   << endl; // prints out random integer
  cout << heap->x << endl; // prints out 0
}
```

Is there any good reason or logic to understand behind this?

Comment: The reason is you did not initialize your variable so any random values are allowed to show up.

Comment: @andre That's not it.  For rts objects yes, but for all heap objects I get zero.

Comment: It is called "undefined behaviour" it can even be so different to spawn demons in your nose.

Comment: @KacyRaye I know it's zero but that could just be luck and change in different compilers or OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance I think it is just coincidence that the heap is already zeroed in the memory that is allocated.

You can read more in the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932781/why-is-a-pod-in-a-struct-zero-initialized-by-an-implicit-constructor-when-creati)

Comment: @JohnDibling Are you saying that `Student* heap = new Student;` will auto-initialise the members of Student?

Comment: I agree with John in saying it's not a coincidence, but I'm going to accept this answer because that link you provided gives a very thorough answer to my question so thank you!

Comment: @KacyRaye why don't you... upvote that answer instead? We can mark this a duplicate then. This will help future SO users.

Answer (score 0):

Always initialize your variable to something meaningful. Else its allowed to take any values at random.

```
class Student {
public:
    int x;
Student(): x(0) {}
};
```