# C++ structures and constructors

Tags: c++, structure

A quick question about structures in C++ that I haven't managed to find the answer for:

I've read that the only difference between structures and classes is the member-visibility. So, does the compiler give the structure a default constructor? (and a default copyconstructor, destructor, and assignment operator aswell?) And can you define all of the above yourself?

Thanks, István

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it does, and yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to all your questions. The same holds true for classes.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that the only difference between structures and classes is the member-visibility.

Thats correct.  Just to note that this includes inherited classes:

```
struct S1 { int m1; };
struct S2: S1 { int m2; };
```

In S2, both m2 and m1 have public visibility.  And an `S2*` can be substituted where an `S1*` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the only difference between a `class` and a `struct` is that class-members are private by default, while `struct`-members default to public. So structures can have constructors, and the syntax is the same as for classes. But only if you do not have your structure in a union.

e.g.

```
struct TestStruct {
        int id;
        TestStruct() : id(42)
        {
        }
};
```

Credit goes to the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127396/structure-constructor-in-c).