# Struct Initialization Arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, struct, initialization

I have a struct, player, which is as follows:

```
struct player {
string name;
int rating;
};
```

I'd like to modify it such that I declare the struct with two arguments:

```
player(string, int)
```

it assigns the struct's contents with those values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although (as has been pointed out), you can simply add a constructor:

```
struct player() {
    string name;
    int rating;
    player(string Name, int Rating) { 
        name = Name; rating = Rating; 
    }
};
```

Is there some reason you don't want to make it a class?

```
class player() {
public:
    string name;
    int rating;
    player(string Name, int Rating) { 
        name = Name; rating = Rating; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Personally, I find having members default to private encourages good design.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid reason, but I simply wanted something for data encapsulation; in this case, it's not important that anything remains private since it's ultimately a piece of a larger class.

Comment: My reason may not be *persuasive*, but it is *valid*.

Comment: My apologies: I pressed the enter key prematurely- I didn't mean to question the validity of your statement.

Comment: Ah, understood. In any case your reasons for doing this are good: such a constructor makes the code more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: @egrunin : When the very first line of your class is `public:` then I'd argue that `class` is just noise. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn : if this were the entire class, I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 8):

you would use the constructor, like so:

```
struct player {

  player(const string& pName, const int& pRating) :
    name(pName), rating(pRating) {} // << initialize your members
                                    //    in the initialization list

  string name;
  int rating;
};
```

Comment: @ildjarn i +1'ed your answer for demonstrating the next best alternative :)

Comment: Just wondering: [why the ampersands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705871/1874170)?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude in c++ the ampersands specify parameters will be passed by *reference*. whether you/somebody feels values or references are superior in this use case boils down to a matter of taste. as in the answer you linked, somebody could outline pros of references and not-so-obvious pitfalls in using values over references. a reference may be slower or faster, or optimized to have equivalent assembly. from a semantic perspective, how could a client screw this up when const references are used and optimizations are enabled? and finally the answer: because it is my convention for c++

Answer (score 8):

Aside from giving your type a constructor, because as-shown it is an *aggregate* type, you can simply use aggregate initialization:

```
player p = { "name", 42 };
```

Comment: For *aggregate* types, see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) answers.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to declare a constructor for your `player` struct:

```
struct player {
    string name;
    int rating;

    player(string n, int r) :
        name(n),
        rating(r)
    {
    }
};
```

In C++ one of the few [differences between classes and structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127396/structure-constructor-in-c) is that class members default to private, while struct members default to public.

Comment: To nitpick, another difference is that default _inheritance_ is public for structs and private for classes.

Comment: Why don't you use an initialization list in the constructor?

Comment: @jogojapan Good to note, thanks for nitpicking :).  Regarding initialization list: also an option.  Stylistic choice on my part I guess.  Is there an advantage to doing so?

Comment: @ktodisco : One is initialization, the other is not (it's assignment). For semantic reasons this can be important (e.g. const/reference data members), and it's never worse with respect to performance.

Comment: @ildjarn Ah, thanks.  I had not considered the case of references.