# Initializing struct with memset

Tags: c++

I've seen code where data structure of such type:

```
struct TestStruct
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
};
```

although it contains `std:string` in it, gets initialized as:

```
TestStruct t;
memset(&t, 0, sizeof(TestStruct));
```

to some my knowledge and other posts I have read, above initialization should
have caused program crash (due to the fact that struct TestStruct containst std::string), but the application seems to not crash, any ideas why?
Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to result in a crash. It is *undefined behaviour*. You still need to fix it.

Comment: You are just very lucky.

Comment: @MarkGarcia I would say unlucky.

Comment: You could use a struct constructor instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1127405/817277

Comment: [Uh-oh Boy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=088c562206c7974baa35894460d6d6ed-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba).

Answer (score 3):

You invoke UB with that, crashing is only one of many incarnations of UB. It may crash later at some (possibly unrelated) point, or not at all, seeming to work.

What might happen in your case is that `std::string` is internally just a pointer to some real string allocation, which is `nullptr` anyways already. But thats just a guess, depends on your implementation, possibly the moonphase, and is not to be relied upon.

Answer (score 3):

The crash might happen because you change an object's internal state. Initialize like this instead:

```
TestStruct t = { };
```

Easier on your fingers and also works in `C`.

Comment: Does this explicitly initialize all the members to 0/null defaults, or do you need a struct constructor for that to happen?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: That link only addresses explicit value specification, your syntax above has empty brackets, implying something like a default initialization.

Comment: ...although the link is explicit that there must be no constructors to use the `Struct S = {a,b,c};` syntax.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore ...and therefore I posted the right link...

Answer (score 1):

It does crash on my 64bit ubuntu when calling string destructor:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b78bca in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b78bca in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7b78c13 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0000000000400808 in TestStruct::~TestStruct() ()
#3  0x0000000000400770 in main ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialization it self may not cause crasches, but using such object is dangerous

Comment: because of     std::string b; inside the struct? what if I had only basic types in it, then it would be ok right?

Comment: Already the memset invokes UB and is dangerous.

Comment: @pseudonym_127 "what if I had only basic types in it, then it would be ok right?" The term used is POD ("plain old data"), and yes, in that case it would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

The `memset` would be setting all the data in the `std::string` object to zero which will, almost certainly, give you *undefined behaviour* which, of course, can include *not* crashing. The stl that I use (StlPort) has a fancy string class that allocates short strings on the stack and longer strings on the heap. That probably would not crash immediately on a zero `memset` but, really, there is no point in speculating as the behaviour is certainly not portable.

You'd be better off writing a default constructor for the `struct`:

```
TestStruct() : a(0){}
```

which explicitly zeros the memory for the `int` and relies on the default constructor for the string.

(Remember that classes and structures are equivalent apart from the default access.)