# difference between classes and structure

Tags: c++, class, structure, theory

I read that the main difference between a class and a structure is that **class is reference type** and **structure is value type**.
can anybody explain me what does the ***value type and reference type means***...?

Comment: Classes can have a constructor and destructor while structures cannot.

Comment: I think you were reading about C#.

Comment: @ForceBru: A struct can have a constructor.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127396/struct-constructor-in-c

Comment: @ForceBru: Complete and utter nonsense. In C++, at least.

Comment: @ChristianHackl,  oops, I'm more a C guy than C++

Comment: @ForceBru: Yet C does not have classes. So it's still nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I meant, I'm not a C++ expert, so I may be mistaken as I know C better as C++. And sure, I know C doesn't have classes!

Answer (score 9):

You must be thinking of a different language. In C++, class types are semantically the same whether you introduce them with the `class` or `struct` keyword. They are object types (which one might loosely call "value types"), in the sense of being objects with a value representation.

The only difference is that base classes and members are public by default if you use `struct`, and private if you use `class`.

Reference types are denoted with `&` or `&&`, and can refer to any object or function type, not just classes.

Comment: I'm not sure if "semantically the same" is a good way to put it. There is clearly a "felt" difference between the two. Using `class` or `struct` is a piece of documentation which immediately gives you a strong hint on whether you are dealing with a loose collection of data or a complex entity with rules and invariants.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: C++ defines semantics, not your heart. While I largely follow that convention, too, it's subjective and not at all close to being universally accepted.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: "Semantically the same" is exactly the way to put it. They denote the same program behaviour (i.e. they have the same semantics), whether or not you read any extra meaning into the choice of keyword.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Of course it's subjective and not *universally* accepted. That's not the point. The point was that "semantically the same" may give the wrong impression that it does not matter at all to anyone which keyword to use, when "most developers" or "most people" (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects) apparently do make a distinction.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: It will only give the wrong impression if you don't know what "semantically" means.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Well, again, that's not relevant to _semantics_ :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Well, I had no intention of entering into a real argument about correct terminology. I'd personally just have used "semantics" as a synonym for "meaning" in a sentence like "[accessibility aside,] they are technically identical but differ in semantics to many programmers". Would you consider such a sentence outright wrong?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Hmm, I think I should reconsider my (programming-related) use of the word "semantics". I can see how it may easily cause me to say things I don't mean.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: If you had no intention of entering into an argument about correct terminology, then beginning your feedback of this question with a criticism about terminology probably wasn't the smartest move ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No no, my intention was virtuous! (I even upvoted this answer.) I sought to eliminate a word which I thought had the potential of misinterpretation and causing fights about terminology :) Oh the irony. In fact, many, many years ago I had a strange internet flamewar in a CSS newsgroup when I was mentioning "CSS semantics" and everyone jumped at me and told me that "CSS has no semantics, only HTML is for semantics". Well, I digress. Have a nice evening!

Comment: @ChristianHackl: lol sounds about right ;p you too

Answer (score 6):

The *only* difference between `class`es and `struct`s is that by default members/bases are `private` to a `class` but `public` to a `struct`.

Now values and references are totally orthogonal concepts in C++ to `class`/`struct`, basically meaning  *instance* of a `class`/`struct` and *handle-to-instance*.

Answer (score 1):

In c++, the only differences between a struct and a class is the default member access and default inheritance:

```
struct A : BaseClassOrStruct { // public inheritance
   int member;                 // public member
}

class A : BaseClassOrStruct { // private inheritance
   int member;                // private member
}
```

However, I usually do make a distinction between them: I use a struct to indicate that my objects really are just a collection of data members (that typically have public access) without methods (other than setters and getters).

Comment: That's not the only difference. See the other answers and the duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza If you think its better now, you could undo your downvote ;)