# Meaning of function call inside a struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct

I have come across structs that are defined seemingly with function calls inside, in some actual c++ code, that I need help to interpret. For example, in [Resource.h from the AOSP](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/tools/aapt2/Resource.h), there is the following struct definition

```
/**
 * A binary identifier representing a resource. Internally it
 * is a 32bit integer split as follows:
 *
 * 0xPPTTEEEE
 *
 * PP: 8 bit package identifier. 0x01 is reserved for system
 *     and 0x7f is reserved for the running app.
 * TT: 8 bit type identifier. 0x00 is invalid.
 * EEEE: 16 bit entry identifier.
 */
struct ResourceId {
  uint32_t id;

  ResourceId();
  ResourceId(const ResourceId& rhs);
  ResourceId(uint32_t res_id);  // NOLINT(google-explicit-constructor)
  ResourceId(uint8_t p, uint8_t t, uint16_t e);

  // Returns true if the ID is a valid ID that is not dynamic (package ID cannot be 0)
  bool is_valid_static() const;

  // Returns true if the ID is a valid ID or dynamic ID (package ID can be 0).
  bool is_valid() const;

  uint8_t package_id() const;
  uint8_t type_id() const;
  uint16_t entry_id() const;

  std::string to_string() const;
};
```

I don't understand this part:

```
  ResourceId();
  ResourceId(const ResourceId& rhs);
  ResourceId(uint32_t res_id);  // NOLINT(google-explicit-constructor)
  ResourceId(uint8_t p, uint8_t t, uint16_t e);
```

Are these function calls? How can they be part of a struct definition? I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052443/c-function-inside-struct) but am not sure if it is relevant/related.

Comment: Do you have a C++ textbook, where this is explained in the introductory chapter? Is there anything in your C++ textbook's explanations of classes and their methods that's unclear to you?

Comment: Reminder: a struct is the same as a class in C++ except that the default category for members (functions or variables) is public. I would suggest it's good programming practice to always specify whether class (or struct) members are public, protected or private. If you do this you in effect make a struct and a class identical. struct is really there to provide original backward compatibility with C code.

Comment: A `struct` is a `class` the only difference is `struct` has default public access and  `class` has default private access

Comment: The question you linked is completely irrelevant - it's about C, which is a very different language.

Comment: Oops, duh. Thanks for all the helpful comments and the answer. I was considering deleting this post, but as I understand it, I can't as there is already an answer with upvotes. Anyway, I'd prefer to upvote and choose it as the accepted answer, so the author can get the points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines are just constructors of `struct ResourceId`:

```cpp
ResourceId();
ResourceId(const ResourceId& rhs);
ResourceId(uint32_t res_id);  // NOLINT(google-explicit-constructor)
ResourceId(uint8_t p, uint8_t t, uint16_t e);
```

Indeed, `struct`s can have constructors: [Struct Constructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127396/struct-constructor-in-c)

See also
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor