# Constructor initialization of a named union member

Tags: c++

This code fails to compile. I get "Expected { or ," at the point indicated. (Xcode 5, so it's a reasonably complete C++11 compiler.)

Is there a way to initialize a member of the nested union in a constructor initializer list, or do I just have to do it in the constructor body?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(): m_bar.m_x(123) { }
private:     // ^ error here
    union
    {
        union
        {
            int m_x;
            float m_y;
        }
        m_pod;
        std::string m_name;
    };
};
```

Comment: What's `m_bar`? There is no such member.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056366/can-i-initialize-a-union-in-a-mem-initializer

Comment: This code declares an anonymous `union` but chooses not to use it.

Comment: @DanO Put in the correct link please :)

Comment: the member is called m_pod... It's just a typo

Comment: Why the union in a union thingy?

Comment: @Jonathan A typo, it should have been m_pod (among the many other issues).

Comment: @StoryTeller In the code this example was stripped out of there was a desire to refer to the POD members alone at one point, hence the union within a union. As it happens that requirement may be redundant, so this whole question may be a nonissue...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a rewritten version of the code fixing various issues:

1. It gives the nested `union`s a constructor: like any other class type, `union`s need a constructor if you don't want to initialize them separately.
2. It gives the nested `union bar` a destructor as its destructor is otherwise `delete`d due to the `std::string` member otherwise (and it needs to deal with the situation that the member may be of type `std::string` which this code doesn't). The relevant clause in the standard is 12.4 [class.dtor] paragraph 5:

   > A defaulted destructor for a class X is defined as deleted if:

   ```
   - X is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial destructor,
   - ...
   ```
3. It also includes the missing header `<string>`.

This is the code:

```
#include <string>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(): m_bar(123) { }
private:
    union bar
    {
        bar(int x): m_pod(x) {}
        bar(float y): m_pod(y) {}
        ~bar() {}
        union baz
        {
            baz(int x): m_x(x) {}
            baz(float y): m_y(y) {}
            int m_x;
            float m_y;
        }
        m_pod;
        std::string m_name;
    } m_bar;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason constructors and unions just didn't come to mind at all...