# Initializing union member in initializer list without narrowing

Tags: c++, initialization, unions, initializer-list, narrowing

In the following code,

```
typedef unsigned long col24;
inline col24 MakeRGB24(int R, int G, int B) { return ...; }

struct blitdata
{
  union
  {
    int Flags, Stretch;
    col24 Luminance;
  };
  // (other members)
};

int main()
{
  blitdata BlitData =
  {
    MakeRGB24(0, 0, 0),
    // ...
  };
}
```

why does the first initializer in the initializer list of `BlitData` give the following error:

> Non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type `col24` (aka `unsigned long`) to `int` in initializer list

Why is the compiler trying to initialize the `int` member of the `union` with the initializer whose type is `col24` instead of using it to initialize the `col24` member?

The compiler suggests that I `static_cast` the result of `MakeRGB24` to `int`, but this could result in an unwanted narrowing.

How can the `Luminance` member be correctly initialized using the result of `MakeRGB24` in the initializer list?

**Edit:** `blitdata` should stay POD.

Comment: *"Why is the compiler trying to initialize the int member of the union"* Because aggregate-initialization (which you are using in `main`) is very simplistic. The first initializer you provide initializes the first member of `BlitData`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056366/can-i-initialize-a-union-in-a-mem-initializer . You need to declare a few constructors.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but don't rely on `sizeof(unsigned long)` to have any particular value, except that it is no less than `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Sorin, unfortunately the struct should stay POD and the union anonymous.

Comment: @zenith Which definition of POD are you referring to? C++03 or C++11? Since C++11, PODs can have user-declared constructors; and C++11's brace-initialization allows even non-aggregates to be initialized with POD-style `{..}` initialization.

Comment: @dyp The code was originally C++98/03, so the initializer worked without the error. Now were porting it to C++11 and this error came up. So I guess it can be turned to a C++11 POD while maintaining compatibility.

Comment: Even in C++03, your initializer in `main` tries to initialize the `Flags` member. However, the conversion from `unsigned long` (aka `col24`) to `int` was not illegal in C++03. So switching to C++11 has uncovered some kind of bug, I suppose.

Comment: @dyp Maybe. I'll look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a nonstandard gcc extension, but this could be what you're after:

```
blitdata BlitData =
{
    Luminance: MakeRgb24(0,0,0),
};
```

If that's no good for you, I suspect assigning it afterwards is the only way.

Comment: That looks a bit like C99's *designated initializers*. However, they'd be written as `{ .Luminance = MakeRgb24(0,0,0) }` as far as I know.

Comment: C99 designated initializers are accepted by clang as an extension in C++ mode, so I'd recommend that over the GCC-specific extension. They are _not_ accepted by cmd.exe (MSVC) in C++ mode, although I believe it supports them in C mode.

Comment: I was under the impression that g++ didn't support them; am I wrong here?

Comment: @Muzer See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6d6e931cf0e22cd "sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported"