# C++ can't implement default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following class:

```
class Fraction {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
    // Constructors
        Fraction(long x = 0, long y = 1);
        Fraction(const Fraction&)=default;//here is the problem
        virtual ~Fraction();
 };
```

I'm trying to disable default C++ constructor to implement my own (I intend to use it for copy). So, I declared it as a default. But, when I'm trying to implement it:

```
Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction&){}
```

Compiler throws the following error at me:

> ./src/Fraction.cpp:16:1: error: definition of explicitly-defaulted
>   ‘Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction&)’  Fraction::Fraction(const
>   Fraction&){  ^ In file included from ../src/Fraction.cpp:8:0:
>   ../src/Fraction.h:22:2: error: ‘Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction&)’
>   explicitly defaulted here   Fraction(const Fraction&)=default;

Is there any way to fix it? What I'm doing wrong ? I found some articles about defaults, but nothing that can help me fix these errors.

Comment: If you want to disable the copy constructor, use `= delete`, not `= default`.

Comment: `= default` tells the compiler to use the default implementation. This also means that __you cannot provide your own__. If you _don't_ want the compiler to create one, simply remove `= default`.

Comment: *Default constructor* and *copy constructor* are two different things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`= default` tells the compiler to use the default implementation. This also means that **you cannot provide your own**. If you *don't* want the compiler to create one, simply remove `= default`:

```
class Fraction {
// ...
    Fraction(const Fraction&); // NO =default
};
```

By the way, the "default constructor" is the one that's called when you don't provide any arguments, e.g.

```
Fraction my_frac; // default constructor called
```

If you want to disable the default constructor, use `=delete`:

```
class Fraction{
public:
    Fraction() = delete;
}
```

Keep in mind that your current `Fraction(long, long)` provides default arguments, so it's eligible as a default constructor.

Comment: But why we have to say to compiler to use default implementation? would it use the default one...by default?

Comment: @Ophelia: That's depends on the context. For example, if you provide your own constructor, it won't generate a default constructor anymore. If you still want to have one, you can simply use `= default`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20829116/1139697) provides some insights.