# Constructor generation

Tags: c++, constructor

I have two C++ structures, `Rect` which is a floating point rectangle and `iRect` which is the same, but with integers:

```
struct iRect {
    int X;
    int Y;
    int W;
    int H;
};

struct Rect {
    float X;
    float Y;
    float W;
    float H;
};
```

Currently I can construct these using the syntax `Rect{1.2, 2.4, 4.2, 0.2};`.

Now I want to make these implicitly convertible, so I create a new constructor for Rect:

```
Rect(iRect iR) {
    X = (float)iR.X;
    Y = (float)iR.Y;
    W = (float)iR.W;
    H = (float)iR.H;
}
```

And I get: `error C2512: 'Rect' : no appropriate default constructor available`
No big deal, I'll just define an empty default constructor.

But now I get `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'Rect'`

So I have to define another constructor for four floats, three floats, two floats and one float to have the same behaviour as before. Also this example is simplified: Rect is actually a union with two `Vec2` types as well so I would also have to define a constructor for `Rect (Vec2 a, Vec2 b)`.

Normally all these constructors are generated by the compiler. Is there any way for me to define my `Rect(iRect iR)` constructor without stopping the compiler from generating all those other constructors?

Comment: Why are you not using classes for this?

Comment: Instead of a converting constructor, you could use a conversion *function* (`operator Rect() const;`). Though I think this is an xy problem

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828907/the-new-keyword-default-in-c11) might be helpful.

Comment: Change `Rect` into `template<class T> class Rect {};` and you can reduce a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello `struct` is a `class` just with different default member access.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello struct and class are essentially synonyms in C++ are they not?

Comment: @dyp That could work, but I like implicit conversion. Not that it's essential, and I'll probably end up doing that but I'm curious to see if there's an answer now!

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I might do that too, but again I'm curious to see if this is possible! What if Rect and iRect weren't exactly the same, so can't be templated.

Comment: _"What if Rect and iRect weren't exactly the same, so can't be templated."_ - In the scope of templating they are identical even if they weren't you can still use specialization. If it makes sense to retain an implementation that can be applied across a wide set of types with partial or complete customization specialization allows that to happen.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Sounds useful, I will look into some of the specifics of templates later on! I've always been put off by how messy template code can get, but I feel like a lot of that is down to the programmers and not the templates themselves.

Comment: You can force the compiler to generate its default constructors in C++11 (eg `Rect() = default; Rect(const Rect&) = default`). The conversion operator's probably better for this specific case though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining a constructor, define a *conversion operator*:

```
struct iRect {
    ...
    operator Rect() const {
        return Rect{X,Y,W,H};
    }
};
```

The conversion operator kicks in whenever an iRect has to be converted to a Rect, either implicitly or explicitly (the `explicit` keyword can be added to restrict it to explicit conversions only). With this operator defined, you can now write

```
iRect a;
Rect b = a;
```

as you'd expect.

Since conversion operators are not constructors, they won't suppress the default constructors - all your aggregate initialization will continue to work.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, although I will add casts to stop the compiler warnings about lost data! I will accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a conversion function. This type of design is implemented in many libraries (Qt comes to mind). Also, your converting constructor takes an iRect *copy* for no reason and you should use C++ style casts when possible. You could simply write:

```
Rect toRect(const iRect& i)
{
    Rect r;
    r.X = static_cast<float>(i.X);
    r.Y = static_cast<float>(i.Y);
    r.W = static_cast<float>(i.W);
    r.H = static_cast<float>(i.H);
    return r;
}
```

Edit: Damn, @dyp beat me to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the advantages of the C++ style casts? To me it seems longer and less readable.

Comment: @JasonLight you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that without constructors, a default aggregate initializer exists, see [here](/q/4178175). When defining a custom constructor (any I might say), aggregate intialization isn't possible any longer.

As others have pointed out though, it is better to define a conversion operator

```
struct iRect {
    //...
    /* explicit */ operator Rect() const {
        return Rect{X,Y,W,H};
    }
};
```

`explicit` can be added so that the casting has to be done *explicitly* for example:

```
iRect r {1, 2, 3, 4};
Rect r2 = (Rect) r; // Explicit cast
```