# Making a copied member reference variable refer to a member of the copy and not of the original

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Consider a code where a struct has a member variable `bar` and a member reference variable that refers to `bar`. For instance:

```
struct Foo{
    double bar;
    double &bar_ref=bar;
};

void receivesFoo(Foo cp_foo){
    //&cp_foo.bar_ref is the same as &my_foo.bar_ref
 }

int main(){
    Foo my_foo;
    receivesFoo(my_foo);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that if you make a copy of a `Foo` by, for example, passing it to a function, `cp_foo.bar_ref` will refer to `my_foo.bar` and not to `cp_foo.bar`. How can I make it refer to `cp_foo.bar` instead?

Note: I use these references variables for naming convenience, as some [tutorials](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/cpp-reference-variable/)  make it look like a possible use and I'd rather avoid all the readability issues associated with macros.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to use the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) of a [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor):

```
struct Foo{
    double bar;
    double &bar_ref;
    Foo():bar_ref(bar){}
    Foo(const Foo& a):bar_ref(bar){}
};
```

This seems to work, but adds an inconvenience of having to maintain two separate  initialization lists with similar code. If you are allowed to use C++11 you can avoid it by doing:

```
struct Foo{
    double bar;
    double &bar_ref=bar;
    Foo(){}
    Foo(const Foo& a){}
};
```

Notice you may encounter similar issues if you use pointers

As @juanchopanza comments, you may also improve the previous example by using the default keyword. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828907/the-new-keyword-default-in-c11) for more details:

```
struct Foo{
    double bar;
    double &bar_ref=bar;
    Foo()=default;
    Foo(const Foo& a){}
};
```

Comment: Maybe `Foo() = default;`  would be more appropriate in the second example. It doesn't mess up value initialization of `bar`.

Comment: @juanchopanza , That's new to me. I've edited the post, please check if it's correct and complete now. Thanks.