# What is the usage of the default keyword in C++

Tags: c++

I have already seen the following exmaple on it's usage:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class A { 
public: 

    // A user-defined  
    // parameterized constructor 
    A(int x)  
    { 
        cout << "This is a parameterized constructor"; 
    } 

    // Using the default specifier to instruct 
    // the compiler to create the default  
    // implementation of the constructor. 
    A() = default;  
};
```

But to me `A() = default;` can simply be replaced with `A() {}`, an empty default constructor. I don't get the point of the `default` keyword here. Am I missing something?

Comment: `= default` is used to replace non-parametrized `A() {}` since C++11 to show it's a default constructor (nothing in the body) as strange as it may seem

Comment: really? why?, i mean what's wrong with `A() {}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828907/the-new-keyword-default-in-c11

Comment: There are actually a bunch of differences between `A(){}` and `A() = default;`. For one thing, `A(){}` blocks aggregate initialization and `A() = default;` doesn't.