# C++ : Default constructor for struct doesn't work?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is a code snipped which is not compilable under gcc 10.2.

```
struct Document {
   int id;

   Document() = default;
};

int main()
{
   const Document test;

   return 0;
}
```

Is it an expected behaviour? I believe that default constructor must initialize all internal members to default value and since `int` is a primitive type it must be 0 (at least in 99% of cases). Am I wrong?

Here is an output :

```
‘const struct Document’ has no user-provided default constructor
```

Comment: You might want to add the compiler warning to your question.

Comment: when something does not compile: read the error message. Please include it in the question (though the message is rather clear)

Comment: "_I believe that default constructor must initialize all internal members to default value_" Why do you believe that?

Comment: fwiw this is a case where gcc's message is more helpful than clangs: https://godbolt.org/z/ThjhKs

Comment: thats not the complete error message (if it is, I strongly suggest to use a better compiler)

Comment: Did you read the notes under said error message, when compiling with gcc 10.2? "_note: constructor is not user-provided because it is explicitly defaulted in the class body and the implicitly-defined constructor does not initialize 'int Document::id'_"?

Comment: Thanks guys for all your comments and links. The main question for me - why default ctor declared the way I did is not a "user-declared" ? What is the meaning of "=default" in this case?

Comment: @Dmitry this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828907/the-new-syntax-default-in-c11

Comment: @Dmitry it is user-declared but not user-defined. Its not really relevant for your question. I don't know why this was brought up. The duplicate that you can find on top should help you to understand why your code didnt work

Comment: @idclev463035818 thanls, just sorted out using the link in duplicate( I've done tons of experiments). The second answer is more useful from my point of view. I love and hate c++ =)))