# Accessing common part of an union from base class

Tags: c++, c++11, strict-aliasing

I have a `Result<T>` template class that holds a union of some `error_type` and `T`. I would like to expose the common part (the error) in a base class without resorting to virtual functions.

Here is my attempt:

```
using error_type = std::exception_ptr;

struct ResultBase
{
    error_type error() const
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<const error_type*>(this);
    }

protected:
    ResultBase() { }
};

template <class T>
struct Result : ResultBase
{
    Result() { new (&mError) error_type(); }

    ~Result() { mError.~error_type(); }

    void setError(error_type error) { mError = error; }

private:
    union { error_type mError; T mValue; };
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<Result<int>>::value, "");

void check(bool condition) { if (!condition) std::terminate(); }

void f(const ResultBase& alias, Result<int>& r)
{
    r.setError(std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error("!")));
    check(alias.error() != nullptr);

    r.setError(std::exception_ptr());
    check(alias.error() == nullptr);
}

int main()
{
    Result<int> r;
    f(r, r);
}
```

(This is stripped down, see [extended version](https://ideone.com/GJaaYb) if unclear).

The base class takes advantage of standard-layout to find the address of the error field at offset zero. Then it casts the pointer to `error_type` (assuming this really is the current dynamic type of the union).

Am I right to assume this is portable? Or is it breaking some pointer aliasing rule?

---

EDIT: My question was 'is this portable', but many commenters are puzzled by the use of inheritance here, so I will clarify.

First, this is a toy example. Please don't take it too literally or assume there is no use for the base class.

The design has three goals:

1. *Compactness*. Error and result are mutually exclusive, so they should be in a union.
2. *No runtime overhead*. Virtual functions are excluded (plus, holding vtable pointer conflicts with goal 1). RTTI also excluded.
3. *Uniformity*. The common fields of different `Result` types should be acessible via homogenous pointers or wrappers. For example: if instead of `Result<T>` we were talking about `Future<T>`, it should be possible to do `whenAny(FutureBase& a, FutureBase& b)` regardless of `a` / `b` concrete type.

If willing to sacrifice (1), this becomes trivial. Something like:

```
struct ResultBase
{
    error_type mError;
};

template <class T>
struct Result : ResultBase
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> mValue;
};
```

If instead of goal (1) we sacrifice (2), it might look like this:

```
struct ResultBase
{
    virtual error_type error() const = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct Result : ResultBase
{
    error_type error() const override { ... }

    union { error_type mError; T mValue; };
};
```

Again, the justification is not relevant. I just want to make sure original sample is conformant C++11 code.

Comment: Regardless of whether this is defined behavior or not, this is fragile as hell. What you seem to want to achieve looks like a sum type, i.e. `Either Error Int`, just with more than two possibilities, right? Like "a value is either an error, an int, a string or a MyObject"?

Comment: @DanielJour Only two possibilities: an error or some T, where for the purpose of this question both are assumed standard layout. I need the union for compactness, so I can't put just the common part in base class. I agree it looks fragile, normally I would use virtual functions but here I want max performance.

Comment: Then what's wrong with a `template<class T> struct Errorneous { union { error_type error; T value;} data; bool is_error; };` ? Why use inheritance here?

Comment: Because I need a limited form of runtime polimorphism, based on common layout instead of vtable. In reality, my 'results' are similar to `Future<R>` and I would like to support `whenAny(Future<T1>&, Future<T2>&, ...)`.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what inheritance is buying you here. Have you seen Alexandrescu's talk on Expected<T>? It's very similar, his implementation is very clean and does not use inheritance.

Comment: Imagine iterating over a vector<ExpectedBase*> to check if any item has exception. Expected<T> doesn't have a non-template base class, so you can't easily mix ham types :).

Comment: I’m pretty sure the reinterpret_cast is not guaranteed to work the way you want.  You can get actual polymorphism through multiple inheritance and dynamic_cast.

Comment: But the objects themselves would contain different things, and you'd have to have another channel to actually extract the type. Honestly if you're going to do this you may as well just stuff them in a boost::any.

Comment: @NirFriedman The objects may contain different result types, but this is irrelevant for certain operations. I have updated the question, hope `whenAny` example makes more sense. When the actual result needs to be extracted, `T` is known so we just read it via derived class. Regarding `boost::any` - I can't use type erasure that relies on virtual methods.

Comment: How can you tell if result contains an error or a `T` value?

Comment: See [extended version](https://ideone.com/GJaaYb).

Comment: Why no virtual methods?

Comment: Also, if your goal is to support whenAny(Future<T1> &, Future<T2>&...), none of this is necessary, you realize that?

Comment: I'd like to support `whenAny(FutureBase&, FutureBase& ...)`, and have already detailed the implementation goals. This is not productive.

Comment: I think the code you've written is guaranteed to be ok. EBCO is required since C++11, and unions are not allowed to have padding at the beginning. Given those two things, the address of the base class and the error must be identical.

Comment: However, I still think this is an X-Y problem. You should write ``template <class ... Ts> whenAny(Ts ... ts)``. You will be able to do whatever you need to do faster if you keep the types around. You started off with a whenAny more like that (earlier in comments), and changed to type erased version. It seems like you are insisting on an implementation independent of whether an alternative meets your goals.

Comment: Thank you for the opinion on conformance. Please expand into an answer if you'd like.

Comment: A templated `whenAny` would work only if the arg count is known at compile time. I'm not sure about the performance benefit (strict aliasing rules might help), though it will affect compile time and binary size. More importantly, what to do when the item count is determined at run-time? `whenAny(std::vector<FutureBase*>)` works for me. Without a base class, you'd need a wrapper for type erasure and this normally relies on dynamic dispatch. I'm not insisting on a particular implementation, just pointing out that none of the alternatives meet all 3 goals.

Comment: It is **not possible** (I mean literally impossible, without resorting to a mechanism equivalent in assembly to type erasure) without using type erasure, oh by the way `std::exception_ptr` is already using type erasure so you ends up using type erasure twice, while using your own type erasure allows you yo use type erasure just once. See my answer, also the answer from PiotrNycz is very good. @ValentinMilea

Comment: Unless you are trying to get rid of `mHasError`in your complete version, it sounds like you should move the discriminator (`mHasError`) to the base class, and use something similar to `Result<error_type>` when you have an error.

Comment: In your real code you are holding a boolean discriminant in the derived class. Why not in the base?

Comment: `std::vector<FutureBase*>` this type, like any C++ type, has `sizeof` determined at compile time. However it is not guaranteed to work as a part of a union.

Comment: @n.m. The discriminant bool could be placed in the base class, but then the derived class would no longer be (formally) standard-layout. To be standard-layout, all non-static data members have to be declared in the same class.

Comment: @n.m. R must be standard-layout, I can't be std::vector.

Comment: That's the point, if you put the bool in the base class, you might not need the standard layout anymore. You would use Result<Thing> for some things, Result<error_type> for others, and could store pointers to both as Base* and access the bool in that Base.

Comment: `Result<Thing>` holds either `Thing` or `error_type` depending on run-time conditions. So it doesn't make sense in my case to have `Result<error_type>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my own attempt at an answer focusing strictly on portability.

Standard-layout is defined in §9.1[class.name]/7:

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base
>     classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

By this definition `Result<T>` is standard-layout provided that:

- Both `error_type` and `T` are standard-layout. Note that this is *not* guaranteed for `std::exception_ptr`, though likely in practice.
- `T` is not `ResultBase`.

§9.2[class.mem]/20 states that:

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using
>   a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is
>   a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [
>   Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a
>   standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary
>   to achieve appropriate alignment. —end note ]

This implies that empty base class optimization is mandatory for standard-layout types. Assuming `Result<T>` does have standard-layout, `this` in `ResultBase` is guaranteed to point at the first field in `Result<T>`.

9.5[class.union]/1 states:

> In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active
>   at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data
>   members can be stored in a union at any time. [...] Each non-static
>   data member is allocated as if it were the sole member of a struct.

And additionaly §3.10[basic.lval]/10:

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic data members (including,
>     recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or
>     contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a char or unsigned char type.

This guarantees `reinterpret_cast<const error_type*>(this)` will yield a valid pointer to the `mError` field.

All controversy aside, this technique looks portable. Just keep formal limitations in mind: `error_type` and `T` must be standard-layout, and `T` may not be type `ResultBase`.

Side note: On most compilers (at least GCC, Clang and MSVC) non-standard-layout types will work as well. As long as `Result<T>` has predictable layout, error and result types are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question:
Is that portable?

No it is not even possible

---

**Details:**

This is **not possible without at least [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques)** (wich do not need RTTI/dynamic_cast, but needs at least a virtual function). There are already working solutions for type erasure (`Boost.Any`)

The reason is the following:

- You want to instantiate the class

  `Result<int> r;`

Instantiating a template class means allowing the compiler deduce member variables size so it can allocating the object on the stack.

However in your implementation:

```
private:
union { error_type mError; T mValue; };
```

You have a variable `error_type` wich seems you want to use in a polymorphic way. However if you fix the type at template instantiation you cannot later change it (a different type could have a different size! you could as well impose yourself to fix the size of the objects, but don't do that. Ugly and hackish).

So you have 2 solutions, use virtual functions, or use error codes.

It could be possible to do what you want, but you cannot do that:

```
 Result<int> r;
 r.setError(...);
```

with the exact interface that you want.

There are **many possible solutions as long as you allow virtual functions** and error codes, why exactly you don't want virtual functions here? If performance matters keep in mind that the cost of "setting" an error is as much as setting a pointer to a virtual class (if you do not have errors you don't need to resolve the Vtable, and anyway Vtable in templated code is likely to be optimized away most times).

Also if you don't want to "allocate" error codes, you can pre-allocate them.

You can do the following:

```
template< typename Rtype>
class Result{
     //... your detail here


    ~Result(){
         if(error)
             delete resultOrError.errorInstance;
         else
             delete resultOrError.resultValue;
    }

private:
    union {
        bool error;
        std::max_align_t mAligner;
    };
    union uif 
    { 
        Rtype               *          resultValue;
        PointerToVirtualErrorHandler  errorInstance;
    } resultOrError;
}
```

Where you have 1 result type, or 1 pointer to a virtual class with desired error. You check the boolean to see if currently you got an error or a result, and then you get corresponding value from the union. The virtual cost is paid only if you have an error, while for regular result you have only the penalty for the boolean check.

Of course in the above solution I used a pointer to result because that allow generic result, if you are interested in basic data type results or POD structs with only basic data types then you can avoid using a pointer also for result.

**Note** in your case `std::exception_ptr` **does already type erasure**, but you lose some type info, to get again the missing type info you can implement yourself something similiar to `std::exception_ptr` but with enough virtual methods to allow safe casting to proper exceptions type.

Comment: `error_type` is a _fixed_ standard-layout type, only the result type varies and even R is restricted to being standard-layout. With these limitations in mind, I propose it may be possible to take advantage of common layout and avoid type erasure. I appreciate the attempted answer, but this is saying _not possible universally_, while the question is more limited in scope.

Comment: What I say is that a standard layout type may have a varying size in bytes, even if you restrict yourself to standard layout, the compiler have to know in advance the size to place it on the stack. Hence you are not only limiting to standard layout, but to standard layout with fixed size. Actually you do not have any check for a particular size.

Comment: Size of derived objects is irrelevant because they are accessed by reference. See goal (3) example.

Answer (score 2):

There is common mistake made by C++ programmers in believing that virtual functions causes higher usage of CPU and memory. I call it mistake even though I know using virtual functions costs memory and CPU. But, hand written replacements for virtual functions mechanism are in most cases much worst.

You already said how to achieve the goal using virtual functions - just to repeat:

```
class ResultBase
{
public:
    virtual ~ResultBase() {}

    virtual bool hasError() const = 0;

    virtual std::exception_ptr error() const = 0;

protected:
    ResultBase() {}
};
```

And its implementation:

```
template <class T>
class Result : public ResultBase
{
public:
    Result(error_type error) { this->construct(error); }
    Result2(T value) { this->construct(value); }

    ~Result(); // this does not change
    bool hasError() const override { return mHasError; }
    std::exception_ptr error() const override { return mData.mError; }

    void setError(error_type error); // similar to your original approach
    void setValue(T value); // similar to your original approach
private:
    bool mHasError;
    union Data
    {
        Data() {} // in this way you can use also Non-POD types
        ~Data() {}

        error_type mError;
        T mValue;
    } mData;

    void construct(error_type error)
    {
        mHasError = true;
        new (&mData.mError) error_type(error);
    }
    void construct(T value)
    {
        mHasError = false;
        new (&mData.mValue) T(value);
    }
};
```

Look at full example [here](https://ideone.com/F4IFAG). As you can see there version with virtual functions is 3 times smaller and 7 (!) times faster - so, not so bad...

Another benefit is that you might have "cleaner" design and no "aliasing"/"aligning" problems.

If you really have some reason called compactness (I have no idea what it is) - with this very simple example you might implement virtual functions by hand (but why???!!!). Here you are:

```
class ResultBase;
struct ResultBaseVtable
{
    bool (*hasError)(const ResultBase&);
    error_type (*error)(const ResultBase&);
};

class ResultBase
{
public:
    bool hasError() const { return vtable->hasError(*this); }

    std::exception_ptr error() const { return vtable->error(*this); }

protected:
    ResultBase(ResultBaseVtable* vtable) : vtable(vtable) {}
private:
    ResultBaseVtable* vtable;
};
```

And the implementation is identical to previous version with the differences showed below:

```
template <class T>
class Result : public ResultBase
{
public:
    Result(error_type error) : ResultBase(&Result<T>::vtable)
    {
        this->construct(error);
    }
    Result(T value) : ResultBase(&Result<T>::vtable)
    {
        this->construct(value);
    }

private:
    static bool hasErrorVTable(const ResultBase& result)
    {
        return static_cast<const Result&>(result).hasError();
    }
    static error_type errorVTable(const ResultBase& result)
    {
        return static_cast<const Result&>(result).error();
    }
    static ResultBaseVtable vtable;
};

template <typename T>
ResultBaseVtable Result<T>::vtable{
    &Result<T>::hasErrorVTable, 
    &Result<T>::errorVTable,    
};
```

The above version is identical in CPU/memory usage with "virtual" implementation (surprise)...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but the question is about correctness not design alternatives. That benchmark is ridiculous - a single iteration, and on ideone? In practice there should be no speed difference in your example because the types are known at compile time and easily optimized. `clang -O3` with at 1000000 iterations shows almost identical execution time.

Comment: Regarding object size being larger than in polymorphic implementation, it's due to padding -- this depends on the max alignment supported for R, and if relevant data can be placed in base class to avoid padding, the non-polymorphic version will end up smaller.

Comment: Finally, I have no idea what implementing vtable by hand is supposed to buy me since the point was to avoid carrying vtable pointer.

Comment: Actually you are right, my answer is more comment to your question. To good answer from @DarioOO (+1) I would add one additional drawback - you do not have virtual destructor in your base class - it is against many principles of OO - in practice you will not have proper deallocation - but I assume you already know that. And regarding performance - yes - you can achieve slightly better performance w/out virtual-ism - but in your case I really do not see any reason for that,,,,

Comment: Virtual destructor supports polymorphic delete -- irrelevant here, because destruction will always be done through concrete type. e.g: `{ Result<A> r1; Result<B> r2; anyHasError(r1, r2); }` with `bool anyHasError(ResultBase& r1, ResultBase& r2)`.

Comment: @ValentinMilea - then to be on safe side - you should prohibit new/delete on your type (e.g. `operator delete ...  = delete;`). How can you be sure that none will ever use your type in a way you did not want it to be used?

Answer (score 1):

```
union {
    error_type mError;
    T mValue;
};
```

Type T is not guaranteed to work with unions, for example it could have a non trivial constructor. some info about unions and constructors: [Initializing a union with a non-trivial constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321351/initializing-a-union-with-a-non-trivial-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Abstract base class, two implementations, for error and data, both with multiple inheritance, and use RTTI or an `is_valid()` member to tell which it is at runtime.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also, I cannnot rely on RTTI / dynamic_cast.